# Why do local maxima of sinc squared function appear *close* to odd multiples of $\pi/2$?

Tags: trigonometry

My question is pretty much the title. I tried two approaches to get local maxima for the $\operatorname{sinc}$ function (I feel it's safe to assume that to know where local minima and maxima of $\operatorname{sinc}$ are the same as to know where the local maxima of $\operatorname{sinc}²$ are).

The first one is by calculating the derivative with respect to the argument, which gives 
$$
x^{-1}\cos{x}-x^{-2}\sin{x}=0\implies\tan{x}=x,
$$
and, as I understand, you can't solve that thing analytically. I figured that, since the minima and maxima of the $\sin$ function are of the form $x_n=\pi/2+ n\pi$, then for $\operatorname{sinc}²$ the maxima would be $x_n$ for $|n|>1$.

However, when solving the first equation numerically (by trial and error) I find that the maxima are close to $x_n$ but are not exactly $x_n$. [This page](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Sinc-squared_function) I found tells the same story.

So, why do the maxima of $\operatorname{sinc}²$ not fall exactly on $x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the graphs of
$\tan(x)$ and $x$,
it looks like there are roots near
and less than
$(n+\frac12)\pi$.

Suppose
$x_n$ is close to $(n+\frac12)\pi$,
so $x_n = (n+\frac12)\pi-d_n$.

Then
$(n+\frac12)\pi-d_n
=\tan((n+\frac12)\pi-d_n)
=\tan(\pi/2-d_n)
=\frac1{\tan(d_n)}
$.

If $d_n$ is small,
then
$\tan(d_n)
\approx d_n
$
so
$(n+\frac12)\pi-d_n
=\frac1{\tan(d_n)}
\approx \frac1{d_n}
$
so,
as a first approximation,
$d_n
\approx \frac1{(n+\frac12)\pi}
$.

By iterating,
you can get
more accurate approximations.

I remember about 50 years ago
finding a paper by Hardy in
an 1930's English math journal
(maybe JLMS)
analyzing the roots of
$\tan)x) = x$.

This is the kind of analysis there,
though, of course,
done much better.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x^2}$$ the first and second derivatives are given by
$$f'(x)=\frac{2 \sin (x) (x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{x^3}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{\left(2 x^2-3\right) \cos (2 x)-4 x \sin (2 x)+3}{x^4}$$ So the extrema correspond to the solutions of $x \cos (x)-\sin (x)=0$ and to the solutions of $\sin(x)=0$. For the last one, it is simply $x=n\pi$.

But
$f''(n\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi ^2 n^2} >0$ meaning that the points where $x=n\pi$ are minima and then the maximum values of $f(x)$ correspond to the roots of $x \cos (x)-\sin (x)=0$ that is to say to the solutions of $\tan(x)=x$.

Now, if you look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TancFunction.html), you will find the approximation of the solutions
$$x=q - \frac 1q-\frac 2{3q^3}-\frac {13}{15q^5}-\frac {146}{105q^7}+\cdots\qquad \text{where} \qquad q=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$